# Predecessor nodes's attributes

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am new with networkx in Python. I am trying to get the attributes of two or more predecessor nodes in a DiGraph.

I have achieved doing the opposite: getting the attributes of the successors nodes with *neighbors*, as follows:

```
A = nx.DiGraph()

A.add_node('S1', e=1)
A.add_node('S2', e=2)
A.add_node('S3', e=3)

A.add_edges_from([('S2','S1'),('S3','S1')])

for neighbor in A.neighbors('S1'):
    print(A.nodes[neighbor]["e"])
```

However, I want to obtain the predecessors's attributes. The problem is that in a DiGraph, *neighbors* only retrieves the successors and not the predecessors.

Based on the picture I attach, I would like to obtain the predecesors' attributes of S1. I have tried with the command *pred*, as follows, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for pred in A.pred('S2'):
    print(A.nodes[pred]["e"])

Output:
'AdjacencyView' object is not callable
```

[image]

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: "it doesn't work" - how exactly does it not work?

Comment: Sorry, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [`Graph.predecessors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html) for this:

```
nodes = A.nodes(data=True)
for pred in A.predecessors('S1'):
    print(nodes[pred])
{'e': 2}
{'e': 3}
```

---

To save specifically attribute `e`:

```
out = dict()
nodes = A.nodes(data=True)
for pred in A.predecessors('S1'):
    out[pred] = nodes[pred]['e']

out
# {'S2': 2, 'S3': 3}
```